# Is Android Circular seekbar overlap possible?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar in my app.
it is working well.But if I want to set a value greater than max is it possible?

```
CircularSeekBar seekbar = (CircularSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar1);

    seekbar.setMax(100);

    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnCircularSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }
    });
```

[image: Above sows 100%[1]]

if I want to set 110% is there any way to achieve it??Like complete one full rotation and extend furtherAlso if any other project/methods can achieve it please suggest.Thanks

Comment: You can keep a counter to store the number of rotations completed and translate that to mean values over 100%